# ingesting data in solr using spark scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, solr

I am trying to ingest data to solr using scala and spark however, my code is missing something. For instance, I got below code from Hortonworks tutorial.
I am using spark 1.6.2, solr 5.2.1, scala 2.10.5.

Can anybody provide me a workable snippet to successfully insert data into solr?

```
val input_file = "hdfs:///tmp/your_text_file"
   case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
   val people_df1 = sc.textFile(input_file).map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1))).toDF()
   val docs = people_df1.map{doc=>
     val docx=SolrSupport.autoMapToSolrInputDoc(doc.getAs[Int]("id").toString, doc, null)
     docx.setField("scala_s", "supercool")
     docx.setField("name_s", doc.getAs[String]("name"))

   }
```

// below code has compilation issue somehow although jar file doest contain these functions.

```
SolrSupport.indexDocs("sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181","testsparksolr",10,docs)
       val solrServer = com.lucidworks.spark.SolrSupport.getSolrServer("http://ambari.asiacell.com:2181")
       solrServer.setDefaultCollection("
testsparksolr")
   solrServer.commit(false, false)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [spark-solr](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr)?

The library's main focus is to provide a clean API to index documents to a Solr server as in your case.